# Нужно ли тут двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Из текста по соционике: "Надо отдать должное(:) Максим, прежде чем наказать, имеет обыкновение объяснять, за что он наказывает и почему".
Правильно ли тут поставлено двоеточие?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, здесь "надо отдать должное" - обычное вводное с оценочным значением. Достаточно обособить запятой.

Хотя допускаю двоеточие как "авторский" знак. Это в том случае, если для говорящего основной смысл сосредоточен как раз в этом отдании должного, а все остальное - только факультативное пояснение.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, кому надо отдать должное. Может быть, лучше сказать так: "Надо отдать должное Максиму: прежде чем наказать, он имеет обыкновение объяснять, за что  наказывает и почему"?